# typedef void(* something)(someclass* something) - what does that mean? Never seen typedef usage like this

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I'm reading linux kernel code and I encounter something like the following:

```
typedef void (* gps_location_callback)(GpsLocation* location）
```

then later it can be used like:

```
gps_location_callback location_cb;
```

Can somebody tell me what does that typedef mean? I never saw something like this before..
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a **function pointer**. Variables of this type point to a function whose signature is `void (GpsLocation*)`:

```
void foo(GpsLocation *);

gps_location_callback f = foo;

// now use f(p) etc
```

Without the typedef you'd have to write:

```
void (*f)(GpsLocation *) = foo;
```

Answer (score 3):

It's making `gps_location_callback` as a `typedef` for a function that returns `void` and takes a `GpsLocation*` as an argument.

So any time you use ore declare a variable of type `gps_location_callback`, you're using or declaring a function pointer that points to a function that returns `void` and takes the arguments that the `typedef` lists.

Answer (score 0):

its a typdef for a function *      its for doing callbacks

so you can then do

```
if(location_cb != NULL)
{
    location_cb(my_gps_location);
}
```

callbacks are good for event based things,   it allows you to pass functions into something that can then be called when events happen.   eg,   when you acquire a gps location, please call my function with the GPS you have acquired so I can do my own thing, like save it to a database, or display it on a screen

Answer (score 0):

`gps_location_callback` is the definition of a *function pointer*, where the function returns nothing (`void`) and takes a pointer to a `GpsLocation` as an argument.

eg. If you had the function:

```
void location_func(GpsLocation* location)
```

You could assign a pointer to the function to `location_cb`, ie.

```
gps_location_callback location_cb = location_func;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is making `gps_location_callback` to alias name of function pointer which take `GpsLocation* location`
as argument and returning nothing;

In this `typedef` now it's easy to make a variable function pointer as u want and you use that as

```
gps_location_callback x,y,z;
```

Now you have three function pointer which takes argument as `GpsLocation* location` and returns nothing.